# Is this mini-DSL for hiding URI passwords compatible with the URI spec?

Tags: security, dsl, uri

## Passwords exposed in URIs

An application stores URIs to be used for file transfers via SFTP, FTP, FTPS and SCP.  Many of these URIs contain passwords, for example:

```
sftp://someuser:sekrit@host.example.com/
```

These URIs are visible to too many people.  We cannot hide email addresses from these people.

## A mini-language to get passwords out of URIs

Using a mini-DSL, we can specify the parts of the email address we don't want to show:

```
sftp://someuser:<<CONFIG:customers/widgitco/password>>@host.example.com/
```

The program that does the file transfer would look for instances of this mini-DSL in the URI, parse them, look up the appropriate strings from restricted sources, and substitute those strings into the URI.  For example, supposing that restricted source contains this key/value pair:

```
customers/widgitco/password: moresekrit
```

Then, after replacement, the URI should be:

```
sftp://someuser:moresekrit@host.example.com/
```

Each instance of the mini-DSL within the URI would be delimited with `<<` and `>>`.  Details of the mini-DSL between the `<<` and `>>` would be free to vary in order to meet future requirements; the only requirement would be that it contain no `>>`.

This would achieve my goal of reducing the exposure of these passwords.

## Is this mini-language fragile?

- Are there valid FTP/FTPS/SFTP/SCP URIs which will break this scheme?
- Are they at all likely?
- What mini-DSL is less likely to be broken by valid URIs?

Comment: Why even bother with this kind of scheme? I mean what's the point? Usernames and passwords don't need to be stored in the URL. In fact, they really shouldn't be. I also think it's a bit much to call this a "mini-DSL" - it's a simple string substitution.

Comment: @Aaronaught - You're right.  I plead "legacy code" and throw myself on the mercy of the court.  The ability to transfer files by FTP &c. was grafted onto a system that thinks it is only sending email.  At one time, these URIs were only email addresses.

Comment: Why do the username and passwords need to be stored in the URI? Why not have a generic mechanism to lookup the username/password based on the URI, instead? Do you really need to have a custom lookup mechanism *per URI* ?

Comment: @Pete In this system there is, with few exceptions, a one-to-on mapping between URIs and passwords, so the lookup _is_ generally per-URI.

Comment: If you generally have a one-to-one mapping between URIs and passwords, why not simply model it as such? Store URIs minus passwords, and have a separate table/configuration/store where given input of URI, returns the password for that URI. Why some custom mini-DSL just for this?

Comment: @Pete I understand your incredulity.  It _is_ a crazy scheme, and not a well-advised one.  Due to the crazy, labyrinthian system, it will cost more time to do it the right way, time that is a rare resource for me, but I think I may need to abandon this scheme even at the cost of more time.  I tried this scheme today, and it is _awful_.  The URIs are a monster to read and work with, and converting the existing URIs to this scheme would be quite a bit of work in itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *Are there valid FTP/FTPS/SFTP/SCP URIs which will break this scheme?* Yes.  Any user that has a password containing "<" or "> is likely to cause problems.
- *Are they at all likely?* Absolutely, since you don't have any control over the passwords used by the users (presumably).
- *What mini-DSL is less likely to be broken by valid URIs?*  None.  Any un-escaped string substitution model, which is all this really is, is going to have problems.